# SwiftUI Async data fetch in onAppear

Tags: swift, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have class `getDataFromDatabase` which has func `readData()` thats read data from Firebase.

```
class getDataFromDatabase : ObservableObject {

    var arrayWithQuantity = [Int]()
    var arrayWithTime = [Double]()
    
    func readData(completion: @escaping(_ getArray: Array<Int>?,_ getArray: Array<Double>?) -> Void) {
       
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        db.collection("amounts").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
            
            if let e = err{
                print("There's any errors: \(e)")
            }
            
            if err != nil{
                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }
            
            for i in querySnapshot!.documents{
                
                let quantityFromDb = i.get("amount") as! Int
                let timeFromDb = i.get("averageTimeRecognition") as! Double
                
                
                self.arrayWithQuantity.append(quantityFromDb)
                self.arrayWithTime.append(timeFromDb)
            }
            completion(self.arrayWithQuantity, self.arrayWithTime)
        }
    }
}
```

I use func `readData()` in `onAppear`:

```
struct CheckDatabaseView: View {
    
    @State private var quantityFromDatabase: Array<Int> = []
    @State private var timeFromDatabase: Array<Double> = []
    @State private var flowersName: Array<String> = ["Carnation", "Daisy", "Hyacinth", "Iris", "Magnolia", "Orchid", "Poppy", "Rose", "Sunflower", "Tulip"]
    @State private var isReady: Bool = false
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false){
            ZStack(alignment: .top){
                VStack(spacing: 40){
                    Text("Hello, world!")
//                    BarView(value: CGFloat(timeFromDatabase[0]), name: flowersName[0])
                    
                }
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
            
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Your datas in database").foregroundColor(.blue), displayMode: .inline)
        .onAppear{
            
            let gd = getDataFromDatabase()
            gd.readData { (quantity, time) in
                self.quantityFromDatabase = quantity!
                self.timeFromDatabase = time!       
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot use values `self.quantityFromDatabase` and `self.timeFromDatabase` because are empty. I know the problem is with the asynchronous retrieval of data. I've tried with `DispatchQueue.main.async`, but I still not get these values. How is the other method to get it? I need this values, because I want to draw charts in `VStack` (the comment line there).

**EDIT**

As @Rexhin Hoxha wrote below, i modified the code but i am not sure if the way is correct. I changed `var arrayWithQuantity = [Int]()` and `var arrayWithTime = [Double]()` by adding `@Published` in class getDataFromDatabase (now it's GetDataFromDatabaseViewModel):

```
class GetDataFromDatabaseViewModel : ObservableObject {

    @Published var arrayWithQuantity = [Int]()
    @Published var arrayWithTime = [Double]()
    
    func readData() {
       
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        db.collection("amounts").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
            
            if let e = err{
                print("There's any errors: \(e)")
            }
            
            if err != nil{
                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }
            
            for i in querySnapshot!.documents{
                
                let quantityFromDb = i.get("amount") as! Int
                let timeFromDb = i.get("averageTimeRecognition") as! Double
                
                
                self.arrayWithQuantity.append(quantityFromDb)
                self.arrayWithTime.append(timeFromDb)
            }
            print("Array with quantity: \(self.arrayWithQuantity.count)")
        }
    }
}
```

also in struct I initialized `@ObservedObject var gd = GetDataFromDatabaseViewModel()` and `onAppear` now looks like this:

```
.onAppear{
            
            self.gd.readData()
            print("Quantity after reading: \(self.gd.arrayWithQuantity.count)")
        }
```

but print in onAppear still print an empty Array. Where did I do a mistake?

Comment: I can not test your code right now but I know one thing for sure. You do not need to use DispatchQueue.main.async because Firebase calls run in the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is in your completion handler. It returns before you retrieve the data.

Solution is to make your arrays @Published and read the data in real time from the view. You have to remove the completion handler.

Call the function on ‚onAppear()‘ and use @ObservedObject to bind to your ViewModel (getDataFromDatabase). This is how it’s done in SwiftUI.

Please capitalize the first letter and use something more generic like „YouViewName“ViewModel.

Your name is fine for a method/function  but not for a Class

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response! I edited the post, could you look on it? I'm sure that I did a mistake, but I don't know where

Comment: your code is fine now. print wont work because you are working with async data. first the function rund and then comes the data. read up on async calls. remove the print from the onAppear and try to print the array count in the view. Use a Text label or smth.

Comment: I did what you wrote, but I have a problem - when I set ```Text(String(gd.arrayWithQuantity.count))``` my label is ```10``` and it's correct, because Array should has 10 values. In case, when I set ```Text(String(gd.arrayWithQuantity[0]))``` I get an error ```Index out of range```. How it's possible. I will read about async calls more, but maybe you just know what the problem is with this error

Comment: It is because the first time the view tries to read the first index of array, the element is not there. Then the element comes from firestore. 1. call function (empty array, index at 0 is nil, throws error. ) 2. dats comes 0 index is there. you can fix it by checking if array[0] != nil {}

Comment: So try to read up on async calls because they are tricky and diff form functional programming. Also ok naming convention. Next step will be MVVM as is the default architecture pattern in SwiftUI. Happy coding.

Comment: Oh ok, I understand now... Thank you for your help I will try to find a solution to this problem on the internet. I hope there is any way to solve this problem

Comment: I added a quick check ```if (Array [0]! = nil)``` then draw chart, but unfortunately I get an ```Index out of range``` error

Comment: try to put the text label inside a foreach loop.

Comment: I have added 
```ForEach(1...5, id: \.self) { row in
                        return Text(String(self.gd.arrayWithQuantity[row]))
                    }``` but still get Index out of range

Comment: I will read up about async calls and maybe will find any solution. Thank you!

Comment: add the array instead of the range. the foreach will update whenever new elements are appended there. again 1...5 will try to print the elements but in async call the elements come later. you can bot do that unless you are extremely sure the element is already there.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did something other - I just created if(array.count != 0) then set value in Text(). It works fine now, thank you for your time and useful tips!

Comment: @Rexhin I found that fetching data inside `onAppear` doesn't work sometimes. When the app UI becomes more complex, the View struct could be initialized many times (the ObservableObject VM will also be re-initialized, resulting in empty data) but `onAppear` won't get called again.